# Query for events in different timezones that start on a particular day

Tags: python, django, timezone

I am trying to write a django website which handles event timing. I would like a calendar view in which I can show events associated with each day.

My initial research suggests best practice is to store all times in UTC including their offsets in the database. My trouble is that if I have two events:

1. Event `A` starts at `2014-05-05 00:20:00+00:00` (just after midnight on a Monday in a zero offset timezone.)
2. Event `B` starts at `2014-05-05 00:20:00+01:00` (just after midnight on a Monday in a one hour offset timezone which is therefore just before midnight in a zero offset timezone like UTC.)

And I want to query all events which start on `2014-05-05` then I do a query like:

```python
monday_start = make_aware(datetime(2014, 5, 5), utc)
monday_end = make_aware(datetime(2014, 5, 6), utc)

events = EventInstance.objects.filter(
        start_datetime__gte=monday_start,
        start_datetime__lt=monday_end,
        )
```

And I only get one event back. Ideally I'd get both as they are both on a Monday in their respective timezones.

If I provide naive datetime objects, ie. no timezone on the datetimes, for the query, I get warnings from Django and still only get one result.

**Question: What is the best way to handle this situation?**

I feel like it might be best to store all times without offsets and then store the timezone of the event in a separate field so that queries can be done against the raw time and then the timezone used for display to the users where necessary. But that might have pitfalls that I cannot foresee.

Comment: Is this more of a programmers.stackexchange.com questions perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're assigning UTC as the timezone to your definitions of monday_start and monday_end. Although Event B starts on Monday from its own perspective, it does not from UTC's perspective, which is what your filter is checking for.

Why not query with naive dates (no timezone info)?

```
monday_start = datetime.combine(datetime(2014, 5, 5), datetime.min.time())
monday_end = datetime.combine(datetime(2014, 5, 5), datetime.max.time())

events = EventInstance.objects.filter(
    start_datetime__gte=monday_start,
    start_datetime__lt=monday_end,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm afraid that using naive dates also only returns one result. Not both. Do you feel that using naive dates should force timezone independent comparisons? I feel like they might be assumed to be UTC or something internally. Also, Python/Django warns if you use naive datetimes objects in comparisons which aware object.

Comment: What about something like:
d = datetime.date(2014, 5, 5)
EventInstance.objects.filter(start_datetime__gte=d, start_datetime__lte=d)
I think that the way you currently store the info is fine, you just need to be able to filter it while ignoring the timezone. Django 1.7 is introducing the ability to have much more complex queries which could allow you filter like start_datetime.day == monday_start.day, year == year, and month == month. But I would like to think we can get the functionality we want without waiting for that.

Comment: Thanks for responding again. I'm afraid that still throws up warnings about naive datetime objects (I think the date might be converted to a datetime for the comparison) and it only returns 1 result. That Django 1.7 stuff sounds promising but you're right, I would think that this would have been encountered before with the Django 1.6 stack. Thanks again.

Comment: It's odd that you're seeing the naive datetime warnings. I've seen them before, but I never got any while testing out the example code I posted here using timestamps in my database. I was using data that was all stored as UTC, though. It's surprising that it still returns one result, as a naive date comparison is exactly what you want to happen.

Comment: Thanks for being thorough enough to check it all through. Could it be anything to do with using Sqlite in my set up at the moment? Might other databases do better? I agree that the naive date comparison would be ideal but I'm having no luck.

Comment: Could you share you're testing code at all? I might be able to try it here and see if it works for me.

Comment: Hm, it could be a SQLite thing. I'm using PostgreSQL. The code I used to test it is exactly what I posted, except I was using one of our model's DateTimeFields instead of an EventInstance, of course. Like I said, all of our stuff is stored in UTC so I wasn't actually able to test that it would work for filtering offsets like Monday -5 being counted as Sunday. But I did not get any complaints about naive datetimes. I'm assuming you're on Django 1.6?

Comment: I'm on 1.6, yes. Thanks again for all the effort. I'm afraid I can't think of what else to suggest. Maybe I'll try again when I have a PostgreSQL setup.